# CSV Matrix into Mysql

Tags: php, csv

I'm trying to get this code working as it's exactly what i'm after:
http://www.reloadedpc.com/php/php-convert-csv-price-matrix-mysql-table/

Although I get this error:

> Warning: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #1 is not an
>   array in C:\xampp\htdocs\matrix\Csv.php on line 580
>
> Warning: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #1 is not an
>   array in C:\xampp\htdocs\matrix\Csv.php on line 580
>
> Warning: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #1 is not an
>   array in C:\xampp\htdocs\matrix\Csv.php on line 580
>
> Fatal error: Cannot access protected property Csv::$field_names in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\matrix\index.php on line 24

Line 580 is the following of Csv.php is:

```
$this->contents[$line_nr][(int) $position] = array_merge( $this->contents[$line_nr][(int) $position] );
```

and Line 24 (and 23) of index.php is:

```
//get the row of width increments
$stack = $csv->field_names;
```

The Csv.php file can be viewed here:
http://hg.mijnpraktijk.com/csv-library/src/e4397b31002d/Csv.php

Any suggestions?

Thanks Guys.

**-EDIT-**
The whole code block is:

```
 foreach ( $this->contents as $line_nr => $line )
                {

                        if ( array_key_exists( (int) $position, $this->contents[$line_nr] ) )
                        {
                             $return[$line_nr] = $this->contents[$line_nr][(int) $position];
                                unset( $this->contents[$line_nr][(int) $position] );
                                // reindex after removal
                                $this->contents[$line_nr][(int) $position] = array_merge($this->contents[$line_nr][(int) $position] );
                        }
                }
```

It seems to unset it. $this->contents[$line_nr][(int) $position] is header of the matrix.

Comment: Have you done any debugging to see what `$this->contents[$line_nr][(int) $position]` actually is?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the last line of the error, it says:

> Fatal error: Cannot access protected property Csv::$field_names in C:\xampp\htdocs\matrix\index.php on line 24

now go to the Csv.php link you posted and look in the code and you'll see that indeed `field_names` is defined as: `protected $field_names = array();`, this means you cannot access it directly unless you extend the Csv class.

If you don't want to extend this class just use the public method:

```
$csv->get_field_names();
```